# WPLMS : Wordpress Visual editior doesn't make any change

Tags: wordpress

when i am trying to edit some text in my wplms theme using visual editor , It do the edit successfully but when i open the website again there is no effect , i 've also tried to clear caches 
thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO! This site is only for specific coding problems, so your question is likely better asked on [super user](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you save your progress?
Make the sure to press the update button.
if you are
try ctrl + shift + R to fully reload the page.
if still not working try to update wordpress or contact the support team they'll help you

Comment: ofc i do this , when i refresh changes is in files but no changes in page

Comment: well , try ctrl + shift + R to fully reload the page. if still not working try to update wordpress or contact the support team they'll help you.